# How to prevent FOV from changing?

Tags: pc, far-cry-4

In Far Cry 4 the FOV automatically changes during certain animations/actions like for example opening a door, entering a vehicle or activating your wing suit. This is really annoying so I was wondering if there's any way you can prevent it from doing that?

I have it set to maximum and as soon as I open a door (for example) it "zooms in" to minimum only to "zoom out" again a second later. It looks like Hitchcock's contrazoom...

Edit: Having played a few more hours now I've noticed the FOV changes **all the time**. As soon as you do anything other than run around it goes back to the default (or whatever it is on consoles).

Open a door, use the grappling hook, climb a ladder, open your parachute, enter a vehicle etc etc etc. It zooms in and out constantly and it's **well annoying**. This never happened in FC3 as far as I can remember.

In cutscenes too of course, but I can accept that even if I think it's slightly lazy of the developers. One thing I can't accept though is the forced VSync in cutscenes. It locks to the nearest multiple of 30 it seems, and unfortunately for me that normally means 30 even though I'd say my average is around 50 when running around.

Are there any mods available for this game? Would be nice to turn these annoyances off.

Comment: The FOV changes to try to simulate your vision while sky-diving for instance. What device are you using to play the game though (ps4, xbox one, pc, etc)?

Comment: While that may be true it's still very annoying. And it happens as soon as I open a door too. Don't see why my FOV would change while opening a door. I believe the reason they do it is to ensure there are no clipping issues with certain first person animations. I'm running it on PC. Pretty sure you can't change FOV on anything else?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf btw I understand what you're talking about now. They increase the FOV to give you more of a sense of speed. They seem to have mucked that up too tho, just check this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/wy3Klzz.jpg. They may have fixed this tho or I just haven't reached enough speed.

Comment: Locked FOV in cutscenes is the opposite of "lazy" in my opinion. The developer has likely created cutscenes for a certain FOV and aspect ratio, increasing field of view can at worst reveal unfinished areas.

Comment: Hence the laziness. Instead of making sure the game works in any FOV they simply lock it.